# How to call a Drools excel decision table function

Tags: java, excel, drools, rules

I have a drools decision table created in excel. I have created a function in the headers section
`Functions | function boolean checkLimits(Policy policy) {
           |    ...function body...
           |    return false;
           | }`
How do I call this function from the CONDITION cell?

I have tried just `checkLimits(policy);`, `Functions.checkLimits(policy);` and `this.checkLimits(policy);` but I get an error all similar to:

`text=Unable to Analyse Expression Functions.checkLimits(policy):
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: com.chubb.Result.Functions()]
[Near : {... Functions.checkSectionLimits(p ....}]`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you call 'headers section' the place you have defined the RuleSet, Import, Variables, etc. This is the place where the functions should be defined.

For a rule to invoke the function, you should call it on the same column as the ACTION cell and on the second row under the ACTION like in the following screenshot

[image: drools decision table]

The function is always called and you can pass the cell's text as a String using $param keyword. In the above example, if the session has the key 'RUL-001' inserted, the RULE-001 will NOT be fired as the function returns false if the code is 'F'.